# Wifi not working in raspberry pi 0 when booting from usb

Tags: raspbian, wifi, usb, boot, raspberry-pi-os

I am using raspberry pi os in raspberry pi 0 w I booted from USB after editing the config.txt file but the wifi is not working on my USB boot it says there is no wireless LAN, I wanted to know 2 things

1)Can we disable USB boot and instead boot from sd card
2)Can we add wifi drivers to raspberry pi os

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't boot a Pi Zero from USB. It always boots from SD Card.
2. The Pi Zero doesn't have Wifi

If you want to boot from SD Card I suggest you do a fresh installation of *Raspberry Pi OS*. It includes ALL the firmware required. Use a new SD Card if you have data you want to keep.

Comment: 2. OP states he has a `raspberry pi 0 w` :p

Comment: 1. you're right, but if you have an sd card with only "bootcode.bin" on it, a pi will perform the rest of the boot from USB (at least pi1/2 will - never tried with a pi 0)

Comment: wow - don't be a newbie here, right